# ASP.NET Convert true/false to Yes/No

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller

I am new in ASP.NET and I am trying to convert True/False value to Yes/No.

```
 <th>
   Arbitration
 </th>

<td>
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Arb)
</td>
```

What is the best way to do it ?

Comment: How was `Arb` property declared? You can convert it from controller action method with ternary operator, like `(Arb == true) ? "Yes" : "No"`.

Comment: public bool Arb {get; set;}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use an extension

```
NFdocs.Models 
{ 
    public static class BoolExt 
    { 
        public static string ToYesNo(this bool? val) => (val ?? false) ? "Yes" : "No"; }
    }
}
```

Then in view

```
@using NFdocs.Models 

<span>@item.Arb.ToYesNo()</span>
```

Comment: 'bool?' does not contain a definition for 'YesNo' and no extension method 'YesNo' accepting a first argument of type 'bool?' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @model IEnumerable<NFdocs.Models.Contact> I added it but still have error

Comment: I add the namespace namespace NFdocs.Models
  {
    public static class BoolExt
    {
        public static string ToYesNo(this bool val) => val ? "Yes" : "No";
    }
And In View I add @using NFdocs.Models;
But still same problem

Comment: You cannot use a method in `DisplayFor()` - even if OP fixes the other issues, you code will throw a _Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions_ error

Comment: Note that with your previous code, all you needed was `@item.Arb.ToYesNo()`

Comment: @MarcusHöglund Still doesn work, I get a banch of errors

Comment: No, What I meant was (say) `<span>@item.Arb.ToYesNo()</span>` - you cannot use a method in `DisplayFor()` - but display for just outputs text, so there is no need to use `DisplayFor()` unless the property is `DateTime` or a numeric type and has a `[DisplayFormat]` attribute (or you have a custom `DisplayTemplate` for the type)

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks again.. you should post this as an answer..without your help I would not know

Comment: @MarcusHöglund Still have problem

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1929 'bool?' does not contain a definition for 'ToYesNo' and the best extension method overload 'BoolExt.ToYesNo(bool)' requires a receiver of type 'bool'

Comment: @Dennix, Your comment in the question stated the property was `bool`, not `bool?` - if its really `bool`, then the extension method needs to be adjusted to suit that

Comment: public bool? Arb { get; set; } this is how I declare Arb in my model

Comment: @Dennix updated the extension method to suit the nullable bool

Comment: @MarcusHöglund Thank you bro soo much :) 
Now, working perfect :)

Comment: @Dennix Np:) you should thank Stephen aswell, go to his profile and upvote some to give him some cred

Comment: @MarcusHöglund - I assume that was you who gave me a up votes on my top 4 answers? If, so, you should not have. Votes should be based on the merit of the answer, not the user (and the system will reverse your votes tomorrow anyway - its considered [serial voting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me/126857#126857))